# The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it django

Tags: python, django, image, deployment, pythonanywhere

I am doing an ecommerce project for deployment in pythonanywhere.com, some error is coming
I would really appreciate if any one could help me to find out the problem as I am a basic learner
TIA

I have developed a online book store application with python and django,I have two MySQL tables  for category and products , while running in local host it works perfectly, but the deployment in pythonanywhere only got problem in images field, also static path given

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXY8i.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCxfc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hXfi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was one of the image field was none, I checked  the admin panel where all the records had images except one row with image attribute empty.After adding image it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Need to Check image is not None with if condition

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>last Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>E-Mail</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
        {% for i in data %}
        <tr>
            
            <td>
                {% if i.image %} # need to check image is not None, this if check if image then render it else not
                {{i.image.url}}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{i.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{i.mobile}}</td>
            <td>{{i.email}}</td>
            <td>{{i.city}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```